# Google Charts: How to create tables with grouped columns names?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, data-visualization

I'm trying to create a table with Google Charts where some data in the column names could be placed in a higher-level column name to help with readability.

In this example, I would like to move "Group 1" and "Group 2" to a 'higher' level; so the left table would end up like the right table.

[image]

I've read through documentation and haven't found a reference for this. Is it possible? If yes, what would be a good approach? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, I'm not expecting any capabilities for ordering by the 'higher' level column names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about something like this (uses jQuery), you can modify for your own custom needs:

https://jsfiddle.net/7tq6sdwc/

```
 google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

  function drawTable() {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
    data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
    data.addRows([
      ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
      ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
      ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
      ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      var tablehead ='<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-head"><th class="google-visualization-table-th gradient unsorted" colspan="4">My Header</th></tr';
      var stuff = jQuery('#table_div').find('thead').prepend(tablehead);

  }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Elegant solution, and easily generalizable. +1 Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm submitting this as an answer because I don't have sufficient reputation to comment, although it's really a comment on the answer by @KevinBrown:

First of all, this is great! I'd upvote, but again lack rep, so for what it's worth, +1.

There is a small bug, however- if the table is large enough to get scrollbars, the added header scrolls with the rows instead of staying put.  I see the "stock" header gets a dynamically-adjusted `style="top: 40px;"` where the top is changed as one scrolls through the table.  So far I haven't been able to get the added header to do the same.  If I figure it out, I'll post here unless someone gets it before me!

Got it:
You need to catch the scroll event on the table, then copy the style property of the stock header rows to your header rows.  There is probably a more elegant and/or robust way, but this is working for me at the moment:

```
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
  data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
    ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
    ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
    ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
  ]);

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

  table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
  var tablehead ='<tr class="google-visualization-table-tr-head"><th class="google-visualization-table-th gradient unsorted" colspan="4">My Header</th></tr';
  var stuff = jQuery('#table_div').find('thead').prepend(tablehead);

  //Add scroll event handler to div enclosing table:
  var stuff = $('#playerTable_div').find('div').scroll(function(event) {
    //my custom header row is the first row in the thead section:
    var myHeaderRow = $('#playerTable_div').find('thead').children('tr');
    //the "stock" header row immediately follows mine:
    var stockHeaderRow = myHeaderRow.next('tr');
    //copy the stock th element's style to mine: 
    var styleToCopy = stockHeaderRow.children('th').attr("style");
    myHeaderRow.children('th').attr("style", styleToCopy);
  });

}
```

Thanks to @Kevin for getting me started!